# JSONP version of JQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jsonp, xss

I am writing a web page widget for my company. This widget must inject an HTML snippet from any domain (our website, possibly a customer CNAME) into the customer's website, which may be on any domain (Tumblr, blogspot, mydomain.com, etc.)

JQuery.load() would do exactly what I'd like it to do, except I don't think it will work with JSONP.

At this point I've chosen on the client-side to use a standard JQuery.ajax() GET call using JSONP that calls to the server.  The server returns an object with a single attribute (the html to inject), which is kind of working except for the fact that I'm still working on making it not choke on the HTML payload. Seems if I escape the HTML, it passes through like a charm, but I'm looking for a better way...

FWIW, I am running RoR on the server-side. Any ideas on best practices to get this to work?

This is the code I'm using on the client:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'jsonp',
url: "http://test.host:3000/widgets/widget_1?username=foo",
crossDomain: true,
success: function(data) { $("#my-div").html.(data.foo) }
});
```

And what I'm returning from the server:

`JQueryCallback({"foo": "<div>bar</div>"})`

And the error I get in the Firebug console:

unterminated string literal (pointing to the beginning of the open tag in the div)

I think its choking on the , but I'm not sure how to get around this, or if this is the best way to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of a typical response? Also, if you're fetching the remote HTML via a local web service, why not just output the HTML and use `.load()`?

Comment: Thanks Phil. When I return JQueryCallback("foo": "<div>foo</div>") I get back an "unterminated string literal" error. Its not necessarilyy a local web service, as the domain of the hosting page and the domain of the server side will most likely be different.

Comment: Amongst other things, one of the issues I was having was the . after html. Removed that and things have begun to act more predictable. Dumb typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help. the main issues I was having was:

1. extra dot after the html() method and
2. I wasn't properly escaping
   the JSON.

I am using to_json now to better encode the html going out.